# Accessing a variable of the another program in C

Tags: python, c++, c

In python, you can learn memory location of variables by using id function, so:

```
X = "Hello world!"
print(id(X)) # Output is equal to 139806692112112 (0x7F27483876F0)
```

I'm tried to access to variable with pointers in C (Surely the other program still alive):

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void){
    char *x = (char *) 0x7F27483876F0;
    printf("%s\n", x);

    return 0;   
}
```

I compile the code, no errors or warnings but when i tried the running program OS giving a Segmentation error. How i can solve this problem?

Or is it possible?

Comment: Each program has it's own virtual address space. So you cannot really do this.

Comment: You would probably need to use shared memory... http://linux.die.net/man/3/shm_open

Comment: Or read the procfs or use `ptrace`.

Comment: For me it's not completely clear what you want to accomplish. But you can't access directly memory that belongs to one program from an other program. Each program has it's own virtual memory. If you need to communicate between two processes (applications) you have different options: shared memory, inter-process communication (IPC), sockets. You can choose an alternative depending on your needs and your system.

Comment: Minus 2? The question is well-written. Just because the *idea* is crazy doesn't make the question a poor one.

Comment: @Bathsheba Even the idea isn’t completely crazy, there are legitimate (albeit *very* few) applications for this. Debuggers do it, as do patchers for games (the legitimacy of those is of course a matter of debate, but unless it impacts other people — e.g. in online tournaments — I find it hard to formulate objections).

Comment: If each program has it's own virtual address space, how Operating Systems can access it?

Comment: "Each program has it's own virtual address space." not true at all environments. ARM Cortex-M for example dont have a MMU and all Tasks running with the same address space.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Doing something like this is more and more impossible these days.  With features like address space layout randomization you can't really tell where a given program, let alone variable will load in actual memory.

Best bet is to use some type of message passing.  Not sure why all the downvotes on your question, but it seems like a reasonably put question, even if not technically feasible these days.